# Is it true that a finite field extension with degree $>1$ cannot be isomorphic to its base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is it true that a finite field extension with degree $>1$ cannot be isomorphic to its base field?

Suppose two fields are isomorphic via the isomorphism $f: E \to F$. Then it is true that using $f$ as an embedding $[E:F] =  1$. However, there might still be other embeddings from $E$ to $F$. Are there any counterexamples of the statement?

Using the comment, let me consider $A= Q(2^{\frac{1}{4}})$ and $B = Q(2^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Apparently $B \subset A$. How to prove the other way around?

Comment: Assuming the adjective "finite" should bind to "extensions" and not "fields", consider any field of rational functions over a field, $F(x)$. Then $F(\sqrt{x})$ is its degree two extension isomorphic to $F(x)$.

Comment: Could you please explain why they are isomorphic?

Comment: It's maybe easier to see that $F(x)$ is an extension of $F(x^2)$ and isomorphic to it, as can be seen by writing an explicit isomorphism: map $f(x)\in F(x)$ to $f(x^2)\in F(x^2)$.

Comment: Surjectivity seems obvious, but how about injectivity?

Comment: $x$ is algebraically independent over $F$, while $\sqrt 2$ is not over the rationals and that's why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: Luroth theorem says that for any nonconstant rational complex function $f(z)$, $\mathbb{C}(z)$ is a finite extension of degree the algebraic degree of $f$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}(f)$ so you can get any degree extension isomorphism this way